# Relationship between C11 atomics and sequence points

Tags: c, language-lawyer, atomic, stdatomic, sequence-points

I basically have the following code snippet:

```
size_t counter = atomic_fetch_sub_explicit(&atomicCounter, 1, memory_order_release);
if (counter - 1 == 0
    && atomic_load_explicit(&anotherAtomicCounter, 1, memory_order_relaxed) == 0 {
      //Some code
}
```

For correctness, it is important that the atomic load of `anotherAtomicCounter` occurs after the fetch-and-sub (FAS) of `atomicCounter`. With the given memory orders, this would normally not be guaranteed and the load could happen before the FAS. However, I was wondering how sequence points have an affect on this particular code. The standard mentions that

> If evaluation A is sequenced before evaluation B, then evaluation of A will be complete before evaluation of B begins.

Combined with rule number 2

> There is a sequence point after evaluation of the first (left) operand and before evaluation of the second (right) operand of the following binary operators: && (logical AND), || (logical OR), and , (comma).

this means that the atomic load must happen after the comparison but the comparison can only be completed once the result of the FAS is known.

My question is whether these rules guarantee that the atomic load always happens after the FAS, even when using more relaxed memory orders?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the second atomic load will happen only if `(counter - 1 == 0) == true` otherwise the second part of `&&` will be skipped as the result of the logical operation is known. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: I know about short-circuit evaluation. My question is, could e.g. the compiler reorder the atomic load before the FAS as an optimization even if the value might not be needed for the right-hand side of the logical AND?

Comment: No - why? It would change the observable program behaviour - which compilers are not allowed to do. BTW what do you mean by FAS?

Comment: I think it can, `memory_order_release` indicates that all operation "before" cannot be reordered. The semantics is 'first modify the object, next release it". Operation that happen after that including "relaxed" operation (which only guarantees atomicity) could be reordered. `&&` guarantees lack of side effects and `atomic_load_explicit` has no side effects as I understand.

Comment: @0___________ what prevents a CPU from prefetching the 2nd atomic load and evaluating it before `counter` is loaded exactly? atomic operations are indivisible, but where is it guaranteed that they cannot be reordered? `relaxed` memory ordering is virtually a `NOOP` and compiler (nor CPU) is obliged to not reorder unlike if it actually had to emit some fence after a release, is it? otherwise `a_a = fetch(a, relaxed); a_b = fetch(b, relaxed);` would, ignoring everything else, be forced to be sequentially consistent among eachother?

Comment: The order in which loads and stores are *evaluated* is not necessarily the same as the order in which they *become visible*!  That's the entire point of memory ordering.

Comment: I see, thanks for the insight! So basically, sequence points have nothing to do with interthread memory orders and only concern the order of evaluation within the same thread. Is that somewhat correct?

Comment: @user16084771: Sequence points do play a role, because the order in which operations are observed depends on the order of evaluation *together with* applicable barriers.  As a trivial example, if you do `x = a.load() + b.load();`, then you cannot say anything about the order in which the loads are observed, even if they both have the strongest `seq_cst` ordering.  Sequence points ensure that the evaluation occurs in a particular order; once you have that established, you can look to barriers and ordering if you want to ensure that other threads see that same order.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge This is a great explanation, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in your title, there is no real relationship between atomics and sequence points.

The code as written does guarantee that the compiler must execute the `atomic_fetch_sub` before the `atomic_load`. But these functions are (in C's memory model) simply requests to the platform to perform certain actions on certain pieces of memory. Their *effects*, when they become visible to who, are specified by the memory model, and the ordering parameters. Thus even in the case when you *know* request A comes before request B, that does not mean the *effects* of request A are resolved before request B, unless you explicitly specify it to be.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I thought. It takes some time to get your head around how these memory orderings work.

Comment: @user16084771: I think ISO C uses some of the same terminology as ISO C++.  "Sequenced before" is part of some conditions for "happens before", but they are separate things.  (And there are multiple flavours of "happens before" which are relevant for different observers, e.g. code in the same thread only cares about sequencing.)

Answer (score 1):

I would say there *is* a relationship, but it's indirect.

Sequence points are how the language defines the *sequenced before* partial ordering on evaluations (C17 5.1.2.3), which is basically what you might generically call "program order".  It's the order that operations naively appear to be executed in, and for a single-threaded program, it completely determines how those operations interact with each other.  It promises, for instance, that if you call `foo() && bar()`, that `bar` will see all the updates to global variables that were made by `foo`; the evaluation of `foo()` will be complete before the evaluation of `bar()` begins.

Now the whole point of memory ordering is that the order in which loads and stores are seen by other threads does not *necessarily* agree with program order.  If you write

```
res = atomic_load_explicit(&a, memory_order_relaxed) || atomic_load_explicit(&b, memory_order_relaxed);
```

then the load of `a` is *sequenced before* the load of `b`, thanks to the sequence point provided by `||`.  But because the memory order is `relaxed`, that is no guarantee that other threads see those operations in the same order.  If we previously had `a == 0` and `b == 1`, and another thread does `atomic_store(&a, 1); atomic_store(&b, 0);` (with `seq_cst` order, let's say) then it is entirely possible that `res` ends up with the value 0.

That's the same as the situation with your example code.  You have a sequence point between the `fetch_sub` and the `load`.  (Actually two of them: one at the end of the full expression that initializes `counter`, and the other at the `&&` which you pointed out.)  So the `fetch_sub` is most definitely *sequenced before* the `load`.  But your memory ordering isn't strong enough to promise that inter-thread visibility matches sequencing.

However, memory barriers can give you more certainty, and what they do is to ensure that, to some specified extent, the order of visibility to outside observers *does* agree with program order.  If you write

```
res = atomic_load_explicit(&a, memory_order_seq_cst) || atomic_load_explicit(&b, memory_order_seq_cst);
```

then the sequence point again guarantees that the load of `a` is sequenced before the load of `b`, and now the `seq_cst` guarantees that other threads see those operations in that order too.  Now `res` will always be set to 1 if another thread does `atomic_store(&a, 1); atomic_store(&b, 0);`.

But memory barriers only impose, at best, as much ordering as the sequencing already provided.  If you instead did

```
res = atomic_load_explicit(&a, memory_order_seq_cst) + atomic_load_explicit(&b, memory_order_seq_cst);
```

now the barriers do not help you.  There is no sequence point between the two loads, and therefore no guarantees whatsoever about the order in which they are even evaluated, much less about the order in which they become visible.

Formally, the *sequenced before* relation is used in defining the *happens before* relation of 5.1.2.4, which is the main tool in determining how loads and stores from different threads affect each other, and in particular, in determining when they do and don't cause data races.